# Deck Rail Fencing For Cat

Tags: deck, fence

I need to install some kind of fencing on the sides of my deck to keep my cat from jumping to the neighbor's balcony (lol). I have pots there now to prevent him from his adventures.

I was thinking a criss-cross or trellis style fencing that wouldn't be too dense and could possibly be used for climbing plants.

I've been having a hard time finding anything like this on Home Depot's website. Any ideas or resources for this? Also on how best to attach it to the deck railing?

Thank you for any thoughts or advice.[image]

Comment: It might be easier just to give the neighbour the cat.  At least then the cat can jump to your balcony to visit.

Comment: @crip659 I guess I should have made it clear that my cat is not trying to escape from my house, he just gets a kick out of jumping over there and back :P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule # one with cats: they will find a way!!!, just to spite you.

I found these on a popular home store site and could be a solution. You might have to do some cutting but you could fasten them to the deck railing with some strong cable ties.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was envisioning something like that, and I just found this, which may prove harder to climb: https://www.homedepot.com/p/48-in-H-x-120-in-L-Willow-Expandable-Fence-or-Trellis-4477217/203580846

I appreciate the cable ties idea. I agree my cat will probably find a way around this too, but it's a good first step ;)